# Get selected option in Select2 event, when multiple options can be selected

Tags: jquery-select2, html-select, jquery-select2-4

How can I get hold on the `<option>` that was just selected when listening to the `select2:select` event? Note that this is simple when using a single-select, as when only one option is selected, that must be the one that was just selected. I would like to also be able to find the option that was just selected when using a multiple-select (`<select multiple>`).

In the `select2:unselect` event, the unselected `<option>` is available through `e.params.data.element`, but it is not so in the `select2:select` event. I do not see a reason why the `<option>` should not be available, since it is created at this time. For the `select2:selecting` event, however, the `<option>` is not yet created, and obviously cannot be available when the event is fired.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've used the following to get the current selected in Select2 (it's for version 4 and up):

```
// single value
var test = $('#test');
test.on("select2:select", function(event) {
  var value = $(event.currentTarget).find("option:selected").val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

**UPDATE: Multi Selected Values (with and without last selected)**

```
// multi values, with last selected
var old_values = [];
var test = $("#test");
test.on("select2:select", function(event) {
  var values = [];
  // copy all option values from selected
  $(event.currentTarget).find("option:selected").each(function(i, selected){ 
    values[i] = $(selected).text();
  });
  // doing a diff of old_values gives the new values selected
  var last = $(values).not(old_values).get();
  // update old_values for future use
  old_values = values;
  // output values (all current values selected)
  console.log("selected values: ", values);
  // output last added value
  console.log("last added: ", last);
});
```

Comment: Won't this just find the value of the first option among the options that are selected? I would like to get the option that was just selected, also if there are multiple options selected.

Comment: Than I suggest not using the .val();

Comment: Yes. To get the option that was just selected, I would have to keep a list of all selected options, and see which option is now selected, but is not in the list. Or do you have a better idea?

Comment: @MagnarMyrtveit I had to revisit this, and have added the multi values retrieval as well. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the question is still not answered. I want the option that was most recently selected, not all selected options.

Comment: @MagnarMyrtveit that's easy, just add a variable outside of the event handler scope, and diff the resulting arrays. I've updated the example above.

Comment: How to do this, without the last selected, but all?

Comment: @eric.dummy do you mean all values? It's in the example above. Maybe you should put some console.log statements than you'll see where the values come out.

Comment: Works fine, except for event defintion. I had to change event from select2:select to change. And in most cases its more useful to get val(). The rest is fine!

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#test').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  console.log(data);
 
});
```